# Why does require return Cannot find module?

Tags: javascript

I have two files:

```
cypress/fixtures/locators/login_page.js
cypress/integration/test-page/steps.js
```

#### login_page.js

```
module.exports = {
    LOGINPAGE:{
        USERNAME: "input[name='j_username']",
        PASSWORD: "input[name='j_password']",
        ENTER_BUTTON: "input[value='Enter']",
        CONTINUE: "input[id='continue']"
    } 
}
```

When I try to require the first file from the second one:

#### **steps.js**

```
const elements = require("../../fixtures/locators/login_page.js");
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module '../../fixtures/locators/login_page.js'
```

EDIT: updated the post with login_page.js content

Comment: `../../` is using the same relative path of where the file you are editing is located. Your code editor should help guide you through where the `login_page.js` is located.

Comment: @Phil post updated

Comment: @Dshiz the relative path looks right to me

Comment: @Phil I recently had this same issue.. give me a min or two and I'll share what I found